# Django login - missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, django

I have simple login view:

```
def logowanie(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(
            username=request.POST.get('id_username', '').strip(),
            password= request.POST.get('id_password', ''),
            )
        if user is None:
            messages.error(request, u'Invalid credentblog.ials')
        else:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next', '/'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, u'User is not active.')

                return render_to_response('registration/login.html', locals(),      
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When i try to go to login page, i get error:

```
TypeError: login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: code seems fine to me, make sure you restart the server after you modify the source code.

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same error. My file urls.py has the route

```
url(r'^login', navigoWeb_views.login, name='log'),
```

I changed it to:

```
url(r'^log', navigoWeb_views.log, name='log'),
```

Check your route.

Answer (score 0):

your code look right, check make sure your import is correct.

`from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your function definition in your `logwanie` view. You are calling the same function with different names

where you are calling the  the function  `login(request, user)`
 change it to `logowanie(request, user)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

We probably have the same error.

I solved it by correcting one line in *urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    ...
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
)
```

into this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    ...
    url(r'^login/$', views.logowanie, name='login'),
)
```

It should be the name of the login view you created, which is 'logowanie' in your case.